# How do I get wires in fallout 4 to connect them to my generators

Tags: fallout-4

I am trying to obtain electrical wires to connect to my generators, but I can't figure out how. How do I connect wires to generators in Fallout 4?

Comment: Reflagging this question for opening. As OP at the original question states, using a lightbulb is very different to using standard electronics. While the answer is still there, theres a lot of misdirection in the extra steps, and the question is not the same.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to construct wires. Just do the following:

In workshop mode, select the generator (it goes green)
Look at the available commands - one will be "attach wire" - select it
Select the target item (radio transmitter etc)
Press the command for attach

This should complete the action

Comment: But you DO need copper to make the attachment.

Answer (score 7):

**Creating Wires**

There's no "wire" object to select from the build menus in the workshop.

Instead, you get close enough to one of the objects you want to connect to interact with it (in workshop mode). You should see an option to "Attach Wire", and the corresponding mapped button. It's Y on the Xbox. Once you've attached the wire to one object, move over to the other object and attach the wire to it using the same button. The option to do so should show up as you hover over the second object. On a large object, you may have to hunt around a little bit to find the right spot to connect to it.

You get experience for creating wires.

Wires have a maximum length. If the two objects are too far apart, you will not be able to connect them. While you are attempting to connect the wire to the second object, you will see a green or red wire hovering in the air. If it's red, that's too far. I'm not certain if there's an absolute maximum length, but if the wire is stretched so far that the lowest part hits the ground, that's too far.

If the two things you want to connect are too far apart, you can build a connector in between and use two wires with the connector in the middle.

To maximize the distance you get out of connectors, you can build the connector right next to the first object, and then move it to the maximum distance afterward.

**Materials**

You need copper to make wires, even though it does not explicitly tell you this. The copper will not be consumed until you attach the wire to the second object. I don't believe you get any scrap back if you destroy a wire or the object that it's hooked to.

**Moving Wires**

If you try to move an object with a wire connected to it, the object will turn red if the wire is either stretched too far or intersects with another object.

You can select and move the individual wires as well. Grab the end, and attach it to something else. The same issues of length and and not intersecting with other objects apply here as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can not actually build a wire. What you have to do, for example, in the mission where you have to clear the starlight drive, for Preston, walk up to the beacon and make sure you have a generator. Walk up to the beacon and press the interaction button and then bring the wire to the generator and press triangle.